# Name for scale contain the notes C, D, E, F G#, A, A#

Tags: theory, scales, terminology, modes

Is this an actual scale mode, like Phrygian, Locrian, etc, or is it just a constructed scale?

```
C, D, E, F G#, A, A# (C)
```

So, root, major second, major third, perfect forth, augmented fifth, major sixth and minor seventh.

Comment: @Dom's answer is more complete than what is available on this website, but it's nonetheless a good starting place if you're trying to identify a scale: http://www.scales-chords.com/scalefinder.php

Answer (score 4):

Yes this scale actually exits and it's a mode of [A Neapolitan Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_scale) which contains the notes:

```
A  Bb  C  D  E  F  G# A
```

This scale starting on C in particular would be called [Mixolydian Augmented](http://docs.solfege.org/3.21/C/scales/nem.html) due to it resembling the Mixolydian scale, but one where you would create an augmented chord off the tonic chord.

```
C  D  E  F  G#  A  Bb  C
```

You can also think of this scale as a mix of major and minor where you would just not use the 5th and both types of 6ths and strictly use the minor's 7th as such.

```
C  D  E  F  Ab A Bb
```

Comment: Augmented tonic... why do Augmented / Diminished modes exist when their tonic triads can't work as "tonic" in standard usage?

Comment: @RailroadHill I'm not sure what you are trying to say. If you are using one of these scale you are probably already a few steps away from traditional harmony so talking about standard usage isn't very useful.